# Making my ViewController conform to NSDraggingDestination protocol

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, protocols, swift5

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with the following code?
I am trying to make my ViewController conform to the NSDraggingDestination protocol and I'm getting an error at the line:

```
self.registerForDraggedTypes(supportedTypes)
```

Telling me that "Value of type 'ViewController has no member 'registerForDraggedTypes'

Here's the ViewController code:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation


class ViewController: NSViewController, NSDraggingDestination {
    
    @IBOutlet var statusScrollView: NSScrollView!
    
    let supportedTypes: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] = [.tiff, .fileURL]
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.registerForDraggedTypes(supportedTypes)
        
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: NSButtonCell) {
        print("check button pressed.")
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Drag and Drop Tutorial for macOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1016-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-macos).

Answer (score 0):

Please check NSViewController has function registerForDraggedTypes(_ types:[NSPasteboard.PasteboardType]) or not.

I think both of your ViewController and NSViewController do not have function call registerForDraggedTypes()

Comment: Clearly there is a lot I do not understand, however I thought that registerForDraggedTypes(_ :)  was a function that was a part of the NSDraggingDestination protocol.

Comment: You have to write the name of the function of NSDraggingDestination protocol into your ViewController and then you can call it in your ViewController.

Comment: Ah... right. I get it.
Thanks for flipping on the switch to the dim light in my head. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`registerForDraggedTypes(_:)` is a method of `NSView` (and `NSWindow`). Call

```
self.view.registerForDraggedTypes(supportedTypes)
```